# Do I always need to rebuild docker in order to install new pip packages?

Tags: python, pip, docker, fig, requirements.txt

I noticed when I try to use docker ( Fig mainly ) to install a new pip package, it does not actually maintain on the system. I must rebuild and install the pip package from requirements.txt

I tried running `fig run web pip install django` and I see the package install, but every time I run the command it reinstalls without prompting to upgrade ( So I know the package install did not stick )

Is this just the inherit design of Docker? I'm confused why building is always necessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the documentation for Dockerfiles https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder.

You should be running

```
sudo fig build
```

with a Dockerfile that resembles

```
FROM centos:centos7 # or whatever
RUN yum -y install python-pip
RUN pip install bottle # or whatever
```

In short, modifications to the file system do not persist container runs.  You need to either build a new image or use a volume.

Comment: Side note: `sudo` isn't necessary if the user running `docker` is in the `docker` group.

Comment: ahh I see. So the important thing to remember is the lack of a file system. Thanks :)